# UIDatePicker outputs different formats of string of date between simulator and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uidatepicker

I ran the `UIDatePicker` on my iPhone and on the simulator, they both show output in different formats?

How can i solve the problem? Is there a format that can work around? I know it is because of `NSLocale`. as I want my app not only to work on one country. I need save the date to the server for searching and comparing. Therefore, I need a format to work around.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Each country should see the date in their own chosen locale's format. You should not force all users to use your chosen format

Comment: I mean anyway to standardise as i would my app to work across the world.

Comment: but i need to update the date users have selected and upload to the server. and i need the date for comparing and search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date format displayed on a `UIDatePicker` is, as you say, dependant on the locale of the device. The simulator is set to en_US by default, I assume your device is different.

Do NOT force user to us a standard format - the date should be displayed in the picker in their device's locale format - using a standard format will be confusing for most of your users. For example, a user in USA would expect to see their dates as MM/DD/YY, in UK DD/MM/YY, in South Africa as YY/MM/DD. If you force a standard format it will be wrong for most of your users. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Regardless of what format is *displayed* in a `UIDatePicker`, the date *selected* by the user and is just a `Date` object. This does NOT have a format, it is just a point in time.

If you're comparing / searching dates, **never** use a formatted date string. Use `Date`, `Calendar`, etc methods.

If you `print` the value of a `Date` object, it will format it using the current locale (but that is just how it's displayed, the date itself has no format)

See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate) for more `Date` info

If you want to send your selected date to the server in a fixed format, you should use `DateFormatter` and set the format/locale to whatever your require. Apple's recommendation is the use `en_US_POSIX` as the locale. Only use this internally, when converting your date to a format for sending to the server - this shouldn't be seen by the user.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter)…

```
let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

/* 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific Standard Time) */
let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFromString(string)
```

In iOS 10+, this has been simplified - you can just use the `ISO8601Date​Formatter` class

Comment: ok. my app won't show the date when selecting a date. but the date of string will be uploaded to the server. therefore, I need to standardise it. but when users draw data from the server, due to the date of string is one format only, I use `DateFormatter` to read to string and feed to the users that depends on their locale.

Comment: therefore, i need to standardise a date format for uploading to the server.

Comment: Ah OK, that is a different question - updated answer

Comment: thanks. I know what to do now. thank you for the advice.

Comment: @CarlHung I see that you've asked 24 questions, 16 of which have been answered, but you haven't accepted _any_. Please review your previous question and _accept_ the correct answer but clicking the  checkmark against it. This will encourage people to answer more of your questions. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: thank you. I think the "tick" below the vote is "accept", right?

Comment: Yes - thank you. You should also check if any of your previous questions were answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to keep the date format a user had selected and NOT modify it, because this is what users do expect.

Step 1)
In case you need to further process the selected date by another function or want to send it to a server in a certain format, create a NSDate object with the locale specific dateformatter:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html

Step 2)
And use another NSDateFormatter that firs to your needs to now transform the NSDate to a NSSTring you can send to somehwere else in a standardizes format.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdateformatter

Another option would be to only display the locale formatted date, but keep a reference to the original Date Object, this way you could skip step 1